# HP Pavilion laptop not booting Fedora 18 LiveUSB

Tags: fedora, liveusb, syslinux

My HP Pavilion g7 1075dx laptop will not boot past the SYSLINUX copyright when booting off a 8GB USB Flash drive that has Fedora 18 KDE Live CD copied to it via LiveUSB Creator. What should I try? I know that since I am getting SYSLINUX copyright, the laptop is booting the flash drive, but then it stops! I have tried several times, and the same thing happens each time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally just went to RadioShack, bought a 10-pack of DVD's, and made a Fedora boot CD. It booted right up, and I am running Fedora right now.